# Find the count of values in a given Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const obj1 = {
  1: 'a',
  2: 'b',
  3: 'a',
  4: 'c',
  5: 'a',
  6: 'd',
  7: 'c',
};
```

For the above code I need to get output as below

```
output = { a: 3, b:  1, c: 2, d: 1 }
```

Comment: This is not considered a good question. Please let the people know what you have tried.

Comment: *"I need to"*: what is holding you back? Have you iterated the object's values? Have you created an output object? Added keys in it? associated counters to it? Incremented the appropriate counter? What is the problem?

Comment: Hi @GauthamShetty welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please share the code what you have tried so far? or where got stuck at?.

Comment: @RamChander The questionar is a member for more than six years :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function works

```js
function countOccurrences(obj) {
  const result = {};

  for (const key in obj) {
    const value = obj[key];
    result[value] = (result[value] || 0) + 1;
  }
  return result;
}
// Input object
const obj1 = {
  1: 'a',
  2: 'b',
  3: 'a',
  4: 'c',
  5: 'a',
  6: 'd',
  7: 'c'
};

// Call the function
const output = countOccurrences(obj1);
console.log(output); // Output: { a: 3, b: 1, c: 2, d: 1 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

A concise / advanced solution would look like this:

```
Object.values(obj1).reduce((o,n)=>{
    if (!o[n]) o[n]=0;
    o[n]+=1;
    return o;
}, {})
```

`Object.values()` gives you the values of an object (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)).

`Array.protoype.reduce()` is a function which takes a function as its argument. Because we want to start on an empty object, we give it `{}` as a second input parameter. The reduce function iterates over all given array values and applying the given function to it. The result is a single value opposed to what `Array.prototype.map` does.
(see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys))

For read-/memorability reasons I choose the parameter names `o` for old and `n` for new for the reduce function.
What we are doing here is simple:

- look whether on the given "old" value (which is in the first step `{}`) exists a key of `n` (`n` is `a` in the first step). If not give it a count of `0`.
- anyways increase the count at `o[n]`.
- return `o`

As you see the `o` is passed in and back the function and it accumulates the count. So this part is often called `accumulator`. But I use `o` because *old* is easier for me to remember than *accumulator*.

Functions like `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.protoype.reduce` ( and don't forget `Array.protoype.reduceRight`) are hard to understand at first. But once understood they will be the best tools on your belt.